# WSO2 Obtain CSR request not replied for a week

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I have requested for CSR a week back to WSO2, but still I have not got back the Signed CSR or Rejection through mail from WSO2. is there is any way, we can contact WSO2 to know the status of the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSR signing process takes a bit of time due to the no of requests and internal verification process. Please fill the [WSO2 contact us form](http://wso2.com/contact/). You will be contacted by on of wso2 officials shorty then you make the enquirers.